# Updating OpenNI and NITE version

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, openni-kinect, nite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the Kinect for person tracking, and I have encountered a bug where OpenNI causes a segmentation fault when many objects move in/out of the frame.  I did some research and it looks like the bug (below) was fixed in a newer version of OpenNI/NITE.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe23b374d in Segmentation::checkOcclusion(int, int, int, int) () from /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures.so
(gdb)
```

My question is, how can I safely update OpenNI to the latest version to work within the ROS framework?

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12895/updating-openni-and-nite-version/) by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2012-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well I'm not sure that I fixed the problem, but I haven't seen the segfault since updating to the latest stable OpenNI binaries [here](http://www.openni.org/Downloads/OpenNIModules.aspx)

---

Originally posted by [bkx](https://answers.ros.org/users/1731/bkx/) with karma: 145 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1